# Может ли поле класса иметь переменное значение в зависимости от переменных других элементов?

Tags: алгоритм, дерево, c++

Есть элемент дерева, в нем одно из полей определяется в зависимости от полей левого и правого листа. Возможна ли такая реализация?

Answer (score 4):

Конечно. Для этого в элементе дерева должны быть ссылки на левый и правый листы.

**UPD**

Это должно быть примерно так:
Элемент дерева хранит в себе три ссылки - на предка и двух потомков, если дерево бинарное. Иначе будет массив потомков. У корня предок всегда пустой, есть метод append, который добавляет потомка, левого или правого. В этом методе, пользуясь ссылкой на предка, установим ему потомка, то есть добавляемый элемент. На псевдоджавакоде примерно так:

```
   class Elem {

        Elem root;
        Elem left;
        Elem right;
        Value value;

        void append(Value value, Side side){
            Elem elem = new Elem();
            elem.value = value;
            if(side == Left)
                this.left = elem;
            else 
                this.right = elem;

            elem.root = this;
        }
    }
```

Разумеется, если потомков может быть больше двух, то надо использовать массив и вторым параметром в append будет что-то вроде индекса.

**UPD UPD**

Надеюсь, идея ясна, а то я тот ещё объясняльщик.

Comment: Как это реализовать, если изначально лист создается с пустыми ссылками на детей, а поле определяется сразу при создании?

Comment: >как это реализовать, если изначально лист создается с пустыми ссылками на детей, а поле определяется сразу при создании

Ну значит пусть и поле изначально будет пустым, а инициализироваться будет, когда листья будут заполнены.

Comment: Как оно может быть изначально пустым, если инициализация происходит сразу при создании объекта, и ты скорее всего имел в виду, когда дерево будет заполнено, но это уже отдельная функция по обработке дерева получается, а не его поле.

Comment: >как оно может быть изначально пустым, если инициализация происходит сразу при создании объекта

Вы уж определитесь чего хотите-то. Получать значения еще не созданных переменных ? Так это вам машина времени нужна, пожалуй. 

Если вы хотите, чтобы одновременно выполнялись взаимоисключающие условия, значит в ваших рассуждениях есть ошибка. Сказать что-то более конкретное можно будет только после того, как вы сможете дать более подробные пояснения по проблеме

Comment: >Как оно может быть изначально пустым, если инициализация происходит сразу


Указатели на листы будут изначально содержать значение NULL